# Download a file from resources with SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot

How can I get a file from reosurces / folderX / file.txt

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/uploadFile", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    /* 
     * FIRST I upload file
     * Next, I need to return different file in this request 
     */ 
    return ResponseEntity.ok().header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + "file.txt + "\"").body();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can serve a resource like this:

```java
@GetMapping(value = "file")
public ResponseEntity<Resource> file() {

  Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("folderX/file.txt");

  HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
  headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"file.txt\"");

  return new ResponseEntity<>(resource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```